# Microsoft DevOps & Azure Functions: Implement recursive updates

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, webhooks, devops

I have a task to implement an Azure Function which is triggered by an HTTP-Webhook defined in Microsoft DevOps (VSTS).

**The idea is as follows:**

- We have a backlog-structure (let's say: Epic > Feature > User Story > Task)
- If i set the state of any of those items to 'Done', all underlying items should also change to 'Done'

**What i have done so far**

- I have enabled a webhook in DevOps which triggers on update of any workitem and sends this item as JSON to an Azure Function
- I have written the Azure Function which is invoked by an HTTP-request and get's the URL of the item which has triggered the request

  - The function then gets all items which are a child of the first workitem
  - The function patches all found child items with the state of the first item
  - All direct children are updated on DevOps

**What i need**
I'm trying to figure out an option to enable recursive update. Not only direct children should be updated, but also all their children (if they have some) and so on.
I thought about the following ways to accomplish this and need your guidance:

- Get all direct children as JSON and then send HTTP-request's to the same function, passing all child item's
- call the function within the function (don't even know if this works) and pass the children as JSON
- find a way to handle all the logic in this single function (dumb foreach-nesting to ensure all backlog-hierarchy levels are processed)

If any code snippets are needed just tell me and i will provide the requested parts (right now i'm quite unsure what part of my code i should publish and would be helpful)

Answer (score 0):

From your list of approaches:

- Get all direct children as JSON and then send HTTP-request's to the
  same function, passing all child item's
  [Please see [Fan-Out/Fan-In scenarios in Durable functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-cloud-backup). This will achieve what you are looking for]
- call the function within the function (don't even know if this works)
  and pass the children as JSON
  [This is not recommended. Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices) for best practices]
- find a way to handle all the logic in this single function (dumb
  foreach-nesting to ensure all backlog-hierarchy levels are processed)
  [Same here. This is not recommended. In general it best practice to avoid long running functions]

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations! I will take a look at the link u suggested, and try to implement it.