# DevOps - API Update Workitems over multiple levels

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

I have an Azure function with an HTTP-trigger, called by a service-hook from DevOps. Whenever a workitem is updated, all child-items of this item should be updated as well, including their childs and so on. I programm in C#.

As an answer to my previous question : [Microsoft DevOps & Azure Functions: Implement recursive updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640749/microsoft-devops-azure-functions-implement-recursive-updates) , i got recommendation to implement an orchestration function to shorten function lifecycles.

I have done this and now my functions look like this:

1. SynchronizeStatus_HttpStart.cs -> implements http trigger and calls the orchestrator function with the the processed HttpRequest as parameter.

   `string instanceId = await orchestrationClient.StartNewAsync("SynchronizeStatus", workItem);`
2. SynchronizeStatus.cs -> implements OrchestratorTrigger and is meant to call the UpdateChildren function for the item that caused the request

   `await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("SynchronizeStatus_UpdateChild", sourceItem);`
3. SynchronizeStatus_UpdateChildren -> implements ActivityTrigger and takes a Workitem as parameter. It then queries for all child workitems, updates the field System.State to the value from the source item and patches all child items on DevOps.

   `var childWorkItemUris = parentWorkItem.Relations
               .Where(x => x.Rel.Equals("System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward"))
               .Select(x => new Uri(x.Url));`

   ```
       var childWorkItems = await vstsClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(childWorkItemUris);

       foreach (var item in childWorkItems)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(item.Url);
           item.Fields.SystemState = parentWorkItem.Fields.SystemState;
           await vstsClient.UpdateWorkItem(item);
       }
   ```

Right now it's possible to update all direct children from the first workitem. My question is, what kind of loop do i need to implement to loop through all possible levels. I think it's gonna be something like this:

- Orchestrator loops over "SynchronizeStatus_UpdateChildren" until some condition is false
- SynchronizeStatus_UpdateChildren returns a list of all child-items which is used in orchestrator to evaluate if looping is still needed

But i'm really unsure how exactly this could be done.